# retrieving data from parse to recyclerview

Tags: android, parse-platform

My code should retrieve the title from parse database and set it to the TextView. when the title to the textview after retrieving it, it shows me a blank TextView with no String.

this is my code

```
final TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
final TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
final TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
final TextView textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Ads");
query.getInBackground("xWMyZ4YEGZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseObject parseObject, com.parse.ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            t = parseObject.getString("title");;
            ParseFile image = parseObject.getParseFile("adPhoto");
        } else {
        }
    }
});
textView1.setText(t);
```

}

why can't i set the String t to the textview, can anyone help me? please.

Comment: Is the above code happening in the viewholder or where?. The best will be to populate a list with the stuff you are expecting from Parse in another method and then pass the list to your Recyclerview adapter and calling notifyDataChanged(). Then in onBindViewHolder(), set the textview to the value of the item.

Answer (score 0):

You have a little mistake, you should set texview after execute query

```
final TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        final TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        final TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        final TextView textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Ads");
        query.getInBackground("xWMyZ4YEGZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject parseObject, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    t = parseObject.getString("title");;
                    ParseFile image = parseObject.getParseFile("adPhoto");
                    // this should be call on ui thread
                    textView1.setText(t);
                } else {
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Dear Mazin; @Piotr answer is valid because GetCallback is executed asynchronous. If you still do not get the title then check the Parse table name and column name.

Comment: the textview did not disapear when i change the location of textview1.setText(t); but the text inside textview1 hasn't changed

Answer (score 0):

You must write

> textView1.setText(t)

in the  done method

Comment: Still didn't work, but the textview doesn't disapear